# Drawing lines between Markers using Google-Map-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'd like to draw simple straight lines between multiple markers on Google Map. I render this map using google-map-react.

Map component

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import Marker from './marker';

export default function Map() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const markers = useSelector(state => state.points);
    const [draggable, setDraggable] = useState(true);
    
    const [center, setCenter] = useState({
        lat: 59.95,
        lng: 30.33
      });
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(14);

    const moveMarker = (key, childProps, mouse) => {
        let markersCopy = markers;
        markersCopy.map(e => e.currPoint === key ? e.currCenter = mouse : e);
        dispatch({type: 'REORDER', payload: markersCopy});
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
                defaultCenter={center}
                defaultZoom={zoom}
                onChange={(e) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_CURR_CENTER', payload: e.center})}
                draggable={draggable}
                onChildMouseDown={() => setDraggable(false)}
                onChildMouseUp={() => setDraggable(true)}
                onChildMouseMove={(key, childProps, mouse) => moveMarker(key, childProps, mouse)}
                >
                {markers.map(e => {
                    return (
                        <Marker
                            lat={e.currCenter.lat}
                            lng={e.currCenter.lng}
                            text={e.currPoint}
                            key={e.currPoint}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    
    )
}
```

I'd like to have them connected by straight lines in the order in which they are
on the list (I'm adding them to the list manually in another component). The resulting line should represent the route, the first point in the list is the beginning of the route, the last one is the end of the route. How can I achieve this?